# Removing HTML element in CKEditor

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ckeditor

I am creating a CKEditor plugin. As part of this plugin, I would like to be able to remove some arbitrary HTML element from the editor's content.  An `<img id="remove-me" />` for instance.

I know I can get the contents (`var contents = e.getData();`) and replace the contents with something else (`e.setData(newContents);`). I know I could do a string/regex replace, but that gets tricky since the user may add some arbitrary attributes or spacing to the HTML.

I would love to be able to use something like jQuery to find and remove the element (like `$("#remove-me").remove()`, but don't know of a way to do this.

Any suggestions?

Comment: You've tried `$("#remove-me").remove()`?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Content of the CKEditor is kept in the element which you can access by [`editor.editable()`](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.editor-method-editable). Then, you can use methods like [`dom.element.find()`](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.dom.element-method-find) or [`dom.element.findOne()`](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.dom.element-method-findOne) and finally you can remove element using [`dom.element.remove()`](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.dom.node-method-remove). You can also access [native DOM node](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.dom.node-property-S-) and use jQuery.

Example using CKEditor API:

```
editor.editable().findOne( 'img' ).remove();
```

Using jQuery:

```
jQuery( editor.editable().$ ).find( 'img' ).remove();
```

Comment: Is this CKEditor 4 only, or is it also available in CKEditor 3?

Comment: CKEditor 4 only. In CKEditor 3 you can use `jQuery( editor.document.$ )`.

Comment: After do that, I get `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'attributes' of null
` when I try to change to html view. Any Idea why?

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like this

```
CKEDITOR.instances.editor_obj.document.getById(id).remove();
```

or

```
editor_obj.document.getById(id).remove();
```