# ckeditor 5 remove an element from the view

Tags: ckeditor, ckeditor5

I try to delete an element/node from the view.

For now i try to do that:

```
editor.model.change(writer => {
    writer.remove(element)
});
```

But I need a element or a range to do so.

So my question : How to get an (or an array of) element from a tag ?

(I found that :  `editor.editable().findOne( 'img' ).remove()`   [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23573839/removing-html-element-in-ckeditor/23573977#23573977)   That's for ckeditor4 not 5 but it is exactly what i need)

Answer (score 2):

You can iterate through all elements of the root and then remove the needed one:

```
let editorModel = editor.model;
let editorDocument = editorModel.document;

editorDocument.on('change:data', (event) => {
    let root = editorDocument.getRoot();
    let children = root.getChildren();

    for(let child of children){
        if(child.is('image')) {
            editorModel.change(writer => {
               writer.remove(child);
            });
        }
     }
});
```